# how to resolve postback of button error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview that contain button and following is the error displayed at its click event.

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled
>   using  in configuration or <%@
>   Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security
>   purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback
>   events originate from the server control that originally rendered
>   them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
>   register the postback or callback data for validation.

Answer (score 0):

**in your aspx file you should put the first line as this :**

```
<%@ Page EnableEventValidation="false" %>
```

if you already have something like  `<%@ Page so just add the rest => EnableEventValidation="false" %>`

Comment: It is helpful but the button event is throwing an exception after its execution and if EnableEventValidation="false" then the little bit of security that is imposed on page will be removed